How to get daily in BigQuery by the individual queries, for the entire project
SELECT 
  creation_time,
  user_email,
  -- location,
  ROUND(total_bytes_processed/POWER(1024, 3), 2) as gb_processed,
  ROUND(total_bytes_billed/POWER(1024, 3), 2) as gb_billed,
  ROUND((total_bytes_billed/1099511627776)*5, 4) as estimated_cost_usd,
  cache_hit,
  state,
  labels,
  SUBSTR(query, 0, 100) as query_preview
FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT

The query above returns only 95 jobs over several weeks, however our BigQuery project is queried hundreds of times daily due to our DBT project running daily, plus data transferring queries that pull from BigQuery and send out to other databases.
I am trying to query/generate a table with those hundreds of queries, filtered for a single day, in an effort to better understand what our largest and smallest queries are each day. I can see the queries here in our PROJECT HISTORY, however they do not appear in the PERSONAL HISTORY, I think because the queries are made using a service account key (and not my personal email address) for authentication.

How can we query to return a table of our daily queries with their associated size/cost?

Are the jobs listed in Project History executed on the US region? The user running the query on JOBS_BY_PROJECT has the permissions to see jobs history?

@DamiãoMartins perhaps not? We use us-west1 for most stuff with regions. The user running the query on JOBS_BY_PROJECT is a project owner/admin will full BigQuery admin permissions, so I would assume they can see the jobs history?

I've tried replacing region-us with region-us-west-1, us-west1, us-west-1, etc and none are working, not sure what the right syntax is

The syntax is [PROJECT_ID.]region-REGION.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS[_BY_PROJECT] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro#region_qualifier https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs#scope_and_syntax

I think the right way might be: region-us-west1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS

this works now!! getting all of the query results across all of the different user emails. Fantastic thank you.

As mentioned by @Damiao we can use the below syntax in the query as mentioned in the google Doc-
Query syntax format -
[PROJECT_ID.]region-REGION.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS[_BY_PROJECT]
EX - myproject.region-us-west1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS
For more details you can refer to the this Google doc for as an example . Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future. Feel free to edit this answer for additional information
